# Chart js :Adding onclick event on slice of doughnut chart is not working in react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, chart.js, chart.js2

I was trying to add onclick functionality on a slice of a doughnut, it's working fine for console.log, but not working if the check function is getting called. Its giving check is undefined.

```
class DoughnutChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  check = (x, b) => {
    console.log("test check");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Doughnut
          data={data}
          height={1}
          width={1}
          options={{
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            cutoutPercentage: 85,
            tooltips: false,
            onClick: function (evt, item) {
              check("source", data.datasets[0].data[item[0]._index]);
              console.log("test");
            },
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DoughnutChart;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have access to 'this' in the function, so you can bind this or use an arrow function like below

```
      onClick: (evt, item) =>{
          this.check("source", this.state.data.datasets[0].data[item[0]._index]);
          console.log("test");
        },
```

Also you will have to call this.check and use this.state.data